# How do I configure my index.js file to support Urdu, English, Dutch and other languages of my react native application

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-redux, locale, urdu

I am new to react native. I have an application that I want to convert in different languages worldwide. I've read some posts about using localization but can't quite understand how to configure or what to write inside my index.js file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Internationalization and localization are complex subjects, even for a simple application, because it touches many parts of the application code, content and user experience. While we may intuitively understand what we want out of a multi-lingual app, developing that app requires special skill.

I'd recommend following a tutorial that can explain the different steps needed to add other languages to your React Native app. You'll need to:

- Create a default React Native app
- Include your dependencies
- Create translation files
- Add multi-lingual support
- Create a drop-down language selector
- Implement useTranslation

Here is an example tutorial that uses **i18next** and **react-native-localize** to create a simple React Native language switcher: https://www.crowdbotics.com/blog/how-to-offer-multi-language-support-in-a-react-native-app